# Custom citation style for technical reports

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing, cite-package

I am using the [authordate3](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/authordate) citation style. This works great form most cases (books, articles). However I also reference some RFCs and I would like to have the RFC number instead of the author and the year when referencing RFCs. It should look like something like

> See (RFC 2822)

I would like to keep using authordate3 for other citations. A BibTeX entry for an RFC looks like this:

```
@techreport{rfc_2822,
author    = "E. Resnick",
title     = "{Internet Message Format}",
institution = "IETF",
type     = "RFC", 
number   = "2822",
year      = "2001",
month    = "apr",
}
```

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using the package `usebib`.

```
%TEX TS-program = arara
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authordate1-4}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@techreport{rfc_2822,
author    = "E. Resnick",
title     = "{Internet Message Format}",
institution = "IETF",
type     = "RFC", 
number   = "2822",
year      = "2001",
month    = "apr",
key = {RFC 2822},

}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{usebib}
\newbibfield{key}
\bibinput{\jobname}
\newcommand\citeRFC[1]{\usebibentry{#1}{key}\nocite{#1}}
\begin{document}
 \citeRFC{rfc_2822}

\bibliographystyle{authordate3}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]